# spring @configuration sax parser exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting the exception below when starting spring mvc web application with bean based configuration. Any ideas?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: com.test.controller.config.MvcConfig; nested exception is java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 108; Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:162) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.54]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_02]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_02]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_02]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_02]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_02]
```

Comment: My fault there was a configuration error when using @propertysource  annottaion....